# windows equivalent of linux's mv?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

I just want an equivalent of "mv dir target", and have dir get moved to target\dir.

- cmd move doesn't even work across filesystems
- powershell's doesn't either
- xcopy doesn't move
- robocopy fails at "robocopy.exe /move p1 p2 dir-in-p1" (the syntax here is the problem, see the accepted answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Robocopy does it fine.

taking the folder logs and moving it into the documents folder (same level):

```
robocopy logs documents\logs /move
```

This worked fine, it moved it without needing a folder created ahead of time and its no longer in the original location.

Comment: Ug, still need to differentiate between a directory and a file as the above syntax doesn't work if "logs" is a file.

Comment: Then use: move logs documents\logs
That will accomplish the task for a file

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what's wrong with running the built-in <kbd>move</kbd> command - it moves across file systems just fine on my desktop (Windows XP).

```
F:\>help move
Moves files and renames files and directories.

To move one or more files:
MOVE [/Y | /-Y] [drive:][path]filename1[,...] destination

To rename a directory:
MOVE [/Y | /-Y] [drive:][path]dirname1 dirname2

  [drive:][path]filename1 Specifies the location and name of the file
                          or files you want to move.
  destination             Specifies the new location of the file. Destination
                          can consist of a drive letter and colon, a
                          directory name, or a combination. If you are moving
                          only one file, you can also include a filename if
                          you want to rename the file when you move it.
  [drive:][path]dirname1  Specifies the directory you want to rename.
  dirname2                Specifies the new name of the directory.

  /Y                      Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to
                          overwrite an existing destination file.
  /-Y                     Causes prompting to confirm you want to overwrite
                          an existing destination file.

The switch /Y may be present in the COPYCMD environment variable.
This may be overridden with /-Y on the command line.  Default is
to prompt on overwrites unless MOVE command is being executed from
within a batch script.
```

Comment: Try moving a directory across filesystems. I get "access denied".

Comment: maybe it's a permissions issue? Which is now especially weird because it worked for me yesterday (as admin on my workstation), but not for my AD account (non admin). There's also the option of `move dir\* [drive:]\path\target` which works for me also

Answer (score 2):

My approach is to install Cygwin and use 'mv'.  But, then, whenever I'm forced to work on Windows installing Cygwin is one of my first actions.

Comment: Ok.. I just don't know how to launch cygwin for a single command from cmd. How?

Comment: An alternative to Cygwin is Subsystem for Unix Applications by Microsoft. It integrates into the Windows cmd shell, so you just type commands as usual.

Comment: Given a full-featured shell, why would you want to use cmd?